# Deploy with Travis to CF with secret environment variables

Tags: travis-ci, cloud-foundry

Currently I have two .yml files, one for the Travis build and one for the Cloud Foundry deployment.

I specified some secret environment variables within the cf-manifest.yml for Cloud Foundry. Due to the secret environment variables, I am not able to use the convenient deployment option Travis offers because I don't want to push the cf-manifest.yml to my git repository.

Is it possible to deploy to Cloud Foundry with Travis and specify some environment variables? If it is, I could then just the encrypt function Travis provides.

Comment: You are aware, that you can encrypt files with Travis, right?

Comment: Yes, but how does that help me? I mean if I use the Travis deploy functionality, I can't no longer take advantage of the Cloud Foundry manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add encrypted env variables to .travis.yml that store following information: cf user, cf password and all the secret environment variables that need to be set later for the deployed Cloud Foundry application

```
env:
  global:
#CF_USER
  - secure: DJSALKDJALKDuiojdklsajdlksajdo83092183jsjsj=
#CF_PASSWORD
  - secure: JDjuuuu1u1717187983198238217321983hHHSHSHSH=
#SECRETENVVARIABLE 
  - secure: JDKLJLKj0888shhshuhdsa45d64dsa1d3sa5d46sads=
```

Maintain a custom deployment within the .travis.yml

```
after_success: 
- curl -L "https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64binary&source=github" | tar -zx
- ./cf api https://api.cf.foo.com
- ./cf login -u $CF_USER -p $CF_PASSWORD -o trial -s testing
- ./cf push myspecialapp -b java_buildpack -i 1 -m 1024M -n myspecialapp -p ./target/myspecialapp.war 
- ./cf set-env myspecialapp SECRETENVVARIABLE $SECRETENVVARIABLE
```

Comment: @gousa once you run `cf set-env` you need to run `cf push` otherwise the environment variables wont take effect. Following is the message from cf 
`TIP: Use 'cf push' to ensure your env variable changes take effect`

Comment: How to encrypt variables to use in .yml files?